# Array return null cant access

Tags: php, arrays, smarty

I have this array -->

```
$datas["Configuration"]["Category"]
```

var_dump shows this:

```
array(7) { 
            ["4"]=> object(stdClass)#950 (2) { 
                    ["Margin"]=> string(1) "0" 
                    ["Increments"]=> string(1) "0" 
                    } 
            ["5"]=> object(stdClass)#951 (2) { 
                    ["Margin"]=> string(1) "0" 
                    ["Increments"]=> string(1) "0" 
                    } 
            ["7"]=> object(stdClass)#952 (2) { 
                    ["Margin"]=> string(1) "0" 
                    ["Increments"]=> string(1) "0" 
                    } 
            ["8"]=> object(stdClass)#953 (2) { 
                    ["Margin"]=> string(1) "0" 
                    ["Increments"]=> string(1) "0" 
                    } 
            ["9"]=> object(stdClass)#954 (2) { 
                    ["Margin"]=> string(1) "0" 
                    ["Increments"]=> string(1) "0" 
                    } 
            ["10"]=> object(stdClass)#955 (2) { 
                    ["Margin"]=> string(1) "0" 
                    ["Increments"]=> string(1) "5" 
                    } 
            ["11"]=> object(stdClass)#956 (2) { 
                    ["Margin"]=> string(1) "0" 
                    ["Increments"]=> string(1) "0" 
                    }
    }
```

If i try to access `$datas["Configuration"]["Category"]["4"]` or `$datas["Configuration"]["Category"][4]` it shows NULL

Im trying to access to this variable in Smarty PHP

Comment: Show us how you try and access it

Comment: About the only way you get numeric string keys like that is if you cast an object to an array.  Try `$datas["Configuration"]["Category"] = array_values($datas["Configuration"]["Category"]);`

Answer (score 0):

> About the only way you get numeric string keys like that is if you cast an object to an array. Try $datas["Configuration"]["Category"] = array_values($datas["Configuration"]["Category"]);

Solved by AbraCadaver
Thank you!